# regular expression not working for m-d-Y

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking date in format ["month"]["/ or -"]["date"]["/ or-"][year]

```
var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/;
    if(dateValue.match(regex))
       return true;
    else
       return false;
```

The above code always return false. If I enter "09/08/2017", it still returns false

Comment: *"Also Please provide..."*.   Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Please help me!!! I am not able write regular expression...

Comment: This is really helpful, try it https://regexr.com paste your regexp there and see what it is doing wrong (there is explain tab)

Comment: @Nida check my answer I have added a demo for you for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var regex = /^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var regex = /^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/ ;
```

demo [here](http://regexr.com/3gqso)

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the slashes '/' inside your regex. try:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/.](19|20)\d\d$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var regex = /(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-|\/)(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(-|\/)([12]\d{3})/;
console.log(regex.test('08/21/2017'));
console.log(regex.test('11-10-2008'));
console.log(regex.test('02.15.2008'));
console.log(regex.test('13/19/2008'));
```

Explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/fKk7Bq/1).